# Java JFrame Plotting Multiple Lines

Tags: java, swing, plot, jframe, paintcomponent

So the crux of my problem is plotting multiple components into one `JFrame` in Java. I'm trying to use the same component twice to plot two different lines, but only one appears. I'm working across three separate classes in separate files, which might be making it more difficult for me. I have tried possible solutions to no avail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186835/how-to-add-multiple-components-to-a-jframe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571818/adding-multiple-components-to-jframe-getcontentpane), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907202/adding-components-into-jpanel-inside-a-jframe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733075/jframe-cant-get-multiple-components-to-display), and elsewhere. I suspect I am doing multiple things wrong, as I'm still trying to fully understand `JFrame`, `JPanel`, and `LayoutManager`s. Can anyone show where I went wrong?

My tester class is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TransportSlabTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Estimation at 100 sections: ");
        TransportSlab slab1 = new TransportSlab(10000,1,5,100);
        System.out.println();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Attenuated Profile");
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TransportSlabGraph component = new TransportSlabGraph();
        //analytical is a method from a 3rd class that returns double[]
        component.attProfileArray(slab1.analytical(),slab1.getThickness());
        frame.add(component);
        component = new TransportSlabGraph();
        //euler is a method from a 3rd class that returns double[]
        component.attProfileArray(slab1.euler(),slab1.getThickness());
        frame.add(component);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now, the class that extends `JPanel`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.math.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TransportSlabGraph extends JPanel
{
    double[] N, xAxes, yAxes;
    final int edge = 100; //Distance from edge of frame
    String[] xlabel = new String[11];
    String[] ylabel = new String[11];

    /**
     *
     * @param inputN Data array of type {@code double[]}
     * @param thickness Thickness set by the original constructor
     */
    public void attProfileArray(double[] inputN, double thickness)
    {
        N = new double[inputN.length];
        //Create labels for the tick marks of the x and y axis from rounded #'s
        BigDecimal bd1, bd2;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            bd1 = new BigDecimal((thickness/10)*i);
            MathContext mc = new MathContext(2); //Round to one decimal place
            bd2 = bd1.round(mc);
            xlabel[i] = String.valueOf(bd2.doubleValue());
            ylabel[i] = String.valueOf((inputN[0]*i)/(inputN.length-1));
        }
        //Set up data array and the axes
        for (int i = 0; i < N.length; i++)
        {
            N[i]=inputN[i];
            xAxes = new double[N.length];
            yAxes = new double[N.length];
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //Get frame dimensions to scale drawn components
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        double xInc = (double)(w-2*edge)/(N.length-1);
        double scale = (double)(h-2*edge)/N[0];
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(edge, h-edge, w-edge, h-edge)); //draw x axis
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(edge, edge, edge, h-edge)); // draw y axis
        //Create evenly spaced tick marks for both axes and label them
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(edge+((w-edge-edge)/10.0)*i, h-edge-10, edge+((w-edge-edge)/10.0)*i, h-edge+10)); //x ticks
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(edge-10, h-edge-((h-edge-edge)/10.0)*i, edge+10, h-edge-((h-edge-edge)/10.0)*i)); //y ticks
            g2.drawString(xlabel[i],(int)(edge+((w-edge-edge)/10.0)*i),h-edge+20);
            g2.drawString(ylabel[i],edge-30,(int)(h-edge-((h-edge-edge)/10.0)*i));
        }
        //Scale data and convert to pixel coordinates
        for (int i = 0; i < N.length; i++)
        {
            xAxes[i] = edge+i*xInc;
            yAxes[i] = h-edge-scale*N[i];
        }
        //Only set the data line's color
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        //Draw the data as a series of line segments
        for (int i = 1; i < N.length; i++)
        {
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(xAxes[i-1],yAxes[i-1],xAxes[i],yAxes[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A component can only be added once to a container

Comment: `Symbol not found: TransportSlab`  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: TransportSlab is a third class I omitted to save space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem #1

An instance of a `Component` may only reside within a single `Container` (once).

You will need to create a new instance of each `Component` you want to add.  I would recommend a factory pattern...

### Problem #2

`JFrame`, but default, uses a `BorderLayout`, which will only allow a single component to reside at each of it's 5 available layout positions.

You will also have problems because your `TransportSlabGraph` class doesn't override it's `getPreferredSize` method, which means that, by default, instance of the component will be provided with a default size of `0x0` by many of the layout managers.

Consider changing the layout manager to something like `GridLayout` to start with.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Like the following?
`TransportSlabGraph component2 = new TransportSlabGraph();`
`component2.attProfileArray(slab1.euler(),slab1.getThickness());`
`frame.add(component2);`